# Result of running code

Tags: python, vb.net, string

My app is in VB.Net. I have a textbox. The user writes a piece of Python code init. I want to run this code. For example, the code in textbox is something like this:

```
print 7*7
```

the result of running this code in Python is `49`. But if the user forgets a space and writes:

```
print7*7
```

the result of running this code in Python is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "vm_main.py", line 33, in <module>
    import main
  File "/tmp/vmuser_jrlbqyaetu/main.py", line 8, in <module>
    print7*7
NameError: name 'print7' is not defined
```

Now I want to save the result of running code (error or correct data) in a string in VB.Net. Questions:

1. What is the data type of the result of running the code?
2. Is it possible to access it?
3. Is it possible to save it? Is it possible to save it in a string? If yes, how?

Comment: The result of calling print depends upon what is hooked up to `sys.stdout`.

Comment: You may want to take a look at this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13807860/execute-python-script-from-vb-net

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```py
import sys
f = open('output.txt', 'w')
sys.stdout = f
###############
#your code here
##############
```

And than all outputs will be written in `ouput?txt`